Only two possible values for $(x_1 + x_2 * \xi + x_3 * \xi^2)^3$ where $\xi$ is a non-trivial third unit root and $x_1,x_2,x_3$ solve $x^3+ax=b$.
The above statement comes from a historic overview that was presented at the beginning of a lecture on abstract algebra. A reference was made to Lagrange, but sadly I could not find what theorem/work stands behind this statement. Could someone please explain why this statement is true or provide a reference for self-study?

Consider the two expressions depending on $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and the choice of $\xi \in \mathbb{C}$
$$s_1 =  x_1+\xi x_2 + \xi^2 x_3, \qquad s_2 =  x_1+\xi^2 x_2 + \xi x_3.$$
The claim is: The values $\{s_1^3,s_2^3\}$ do not depend on the ordering of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ nor the choice of $\xi$.
If you swap $\xi$ with $\xi^2$, then you exchange $s_1$ and $s_2$. If you apply the cyclic permutation $(1\,2\,3)$ to $x_1,x_2,x_3$, then $s_i$ becomes $\xi s_i$, so $s_i^3$ becomes $(\xi s_i)^3 = s_i^3$. If you apply the permutation $(2\,3)$, then you exchange $s_1$ and $s_2$ again. $\square$
Regarding Lagrange's method the references on the Wikipedia page may be helpful.
